# Website homepage to show subdirectory content via htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress website with root located at
http://www.example.com/web

Via htaccess, when I visit that address I would like to see what's on http://www.example.com/web/about-me with the browser still displaying http://www.example.com/web.

Is it possible to achieve this via .htaccess? What I have right now is

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

I tried adding at the bottom

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /about-me/
```

Without any success.

Comment: So that the page you are on does not display in the URL bar? Interesting. I would be interested to hear the answer on this.

Comment: So you want to display both pages simultaneously? I'm confused. Please elaborate on.

Comment: Lee's answer clarifies exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you have a website which is hosted on a sub-directory of your domain, and you want to rewrite the homepage URL to your about-me page, but without the user seeing the URL change. Your main issue is trying to use a Redirect which will change the displayed URL.

This should do it

```
RewriteBase /web                      # Dropped the / suffix otherwise the rewrites get //
## RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] -   # Removed because the Conditions below should be doing this?
RewriteRule ^$ /about-me [L]          # Redirect homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]          # dropped the /web prefix as that is managed by the RewriteBase
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Would I need to replace this with the htaccess generated by Wordpress? Because if I do so, I get a 500 server error

Comment: You should be able to simply replace the relevant lines in your htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you, you actually answered my question but I have noticed that I have asked the question not properly. I thought this applied to a Wordpress Multisite config too. Basically I have this .htaccess https://pastebin.com/tggD4kKX and I am trying to set it up so that when I go to the root I will see the homepage of one of my sites residing in a subdirectory (with the URL not changing). Would love if you could give it a look.